# Why am I getting Escaped Quotes? Json.net

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net, ef-core-2.1

I am not sure if I am doing this right. I got json stored in my database that I want to update.

```
var items = dbContext.items.FromSql("select *, JSON_VALUE(Attributes, '$.serialNumber') as serialNumber FROM Items WHERE JSON_VALUE(Attributes,'$.serialNumber') like '%15830792087%'").ToList();
var attributes = JObject.Parse(items[0].Attributes);
var images = attributes["image"];
if(images == null){
    var newImage = new List<InventoryImage>()
    {
        new InventoryImage()
        {
             ImageUrl = imageBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri,
             OrignalName = file.FileName,
             ThumbnailUrl = thumbnailBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        }
    };
    JProperty newProp = new JProperty("image", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newImage));
    attributes.Add(newProp);
    images[0].Attributes = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attributes);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

what I get in my db.

```
"image":"[{\"OrignalName\":\"cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg\",\"ImageUrl\":\"ed1ab040e710.jpeg\",\"ThumbnailUrl\":\"3c3e73e3-5062-492b-b830-ed1ab040e710_thumbnail.jpeg\"}]"}
```

Comment: How do you look at that string?  Ie, what tool/program?

Comment: Sql server, query results window.

Comment: The server doesn't have any windows, I'm guessing it's the management Studio ?

Comment: Yea sorry management studio. Maybe it's just how it should be? When I look at it in C# through a Json visualizer it looks ok.

Comment: @PeterB - Typo. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
JProperty newProp = new JProperty("image", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newImage));
```

This will serialize `newImage` into a JSON string and then assign that JSON string as the value to the `image` property. So the value of `property` is a string which happens to be a JSON string.

What you should do instead is assign the value directly without serializing it first. That way you avoid a double serialization:

```
Property newProp = new JProperty("image", JToken.FromObject(newImage));
```

Comment: Or rather, `new JProperty("image", JToken.FromObject(newImage));`